# Complex number division

Tags: complex-numbers

If z=a+bj

Can anyone explain why real(z/z*) can't be figured out using =(a-bj/a+bj)
=(a/a)
=1

And imagenary (z/z*)
=(a+bj/a-bj)
=(bj/-bj)
=-1

Comment: Complex numbers aside, $\,\cfrac{a+b}{c+d} \ne \cfrac{a}{c}+\cfrac{b}{d}\,$ in general.

Comment: But when solving just real or imagenary parts can the values not be separated? Or do you need a real denominator to separate the real and imaginary parts?

Comment: Look again, it's just basic algebra regardless of complex numbes or not. You can separate $\,\cfrac{a-bj}{a+bj}=\cfrac{a}{a+bj}-\cfrac{bj}{a+bj}\,$ if you want, but what's your next step after that?

Comment: Why can't a/(a+bj) not be separated into real and imagenary parts a/a and a/bj respectively

Comment: Because $\,\cfrac{x}{y+z}\ne\cfrac{x}{y}+\cfrac{x}{z}\,$ in general. I don't know why you think it would be true for $x=y=a, \,z=bj$.

Comment: if expanded to (a^2 + 2abj - b^2)/(a^2 + b^2) , it can then be divided into real and imaginary parts (a^2 - b^2)/(a^2 + b^2) and (2ab)/(a^2 + b^2) due to the fact of only the numerator being separated into real and imaginary whilst the denominator stays constant correct? if so, why cant the same be done with an imaginary denominator? (if denominator was only imaginary with no real parts would it work is what i'm asking, i understand it cant be simply separated but is conversion to real denominator just so only one type of number is used in denominator?)

Comment: If an algebraic identity doesn't work for real $\,x,y,z\,$ then it won't work for complex $\,x,y,z\,$ either. It's as simple as that. Sorry, but I don't know how to explain it any better.

Comment: I was getting confused due to real and imaginary parts being "separated" but now understand its just a method that doesn't change any of the rules governing the algebra. sorry i'm not very experienced so the question might of made no sense, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Denoting the imaginary unit as $i$, we see that if we have a complex number:
$$ z = a+bi $$
then its complex conjugate is:
$$ \bar{z} = a-bi$$
and so:
\begin{align*}
\frac{z}{\bar{z}} &= \frac{a+bi}{a-bi} \\
&= \frac{a+bi}{a-bi} \frac{a+bi}{a+bi} \\
&= \frac{a^2+2abi -b^2}{a^2+b^2} \\
&= \frac{a^2-b^2}{a^2+b^2} + \frac{2ab}{a^2+b^2}i
\end{align*}
Therefore:
\begin{align*}
\Re \left[\frac{z}{\bar{z}} \right] &= \frac{a^2-b^2}{a^2+b^2} \\
\Im \left[\frac{z}{\bar{z}} \right] &= \frac{2ab}{a^2+b^2}
\end{align*}